# Are Euclidean Distance Matrices non-negative as a consequence of their symmetry and the triangle inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

So I've been playing with Euclidean Distance Matrices these days (EDMs). Super fun.

Obviously I had to list the properties that I expected an EDM would have, right at the beginning of the process, and I didn't realize something  back than, that I've stumbled upon right now.

So let $D$ be an $N \times N$ Euclidean Distance Matrix, which, as the name implies, is the matrix in which **each entry $D_{ij}$ represents the Euclidean distance between two points ${\vec p}_i$ and ${\vec p}_j$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$**.

> **EDIT:** User Thomas Andrews pointed out to me in the comments that this definition isn't the common definition of an Euclidean Distance Matrix. In the usual definition, the elements $D_{ij}$ are **the squares of the distances**. I wasn't aware of that when I first stumbled upon this small proof so I will keep here the original definitions that led me to the question. Beware.

According to what I know about Euclidean distances, I have decided, as a starting point, that the elements $D_{ij}$ of a well-behaved tax-paying EDM should have these properties:

1. **Real:** $D_{ii} \in \mathbb{R} \forall i,j$
2. **Traceless:** $D_{ii} = 0$
3. **Symmetric:** $D_{ij} = D_{ji}$
4. **Nonegative** $D_{ij} \geq 0 \forall i \neq j$
5. **Metric:** $D_{ij} \leq D_{ik} + D_{kj} \forall i,j,k$

The names of the properties are arbitrary, just so we can have a hook on which to hang these definitions. I'm not a trained mathematician, I'm a chemist, there are probably names for these things that I'm not using here and for that I apologize.

So I started playing with these definitions in order to test whether I had all my bases covered. At first I wanted to test whether the property $(5)$ really held for any triplets $(i,j,k)$. So I did what any sensible investigator here would do and set $i=j$ in order to test it.

In that situation, if the matrix is Metric then we have that
$$\
\tag{1} D_{ii} \leq D_{ik} + D_{ki}
$$
But if $D$ is a also Symmetric, then $D_{ik}=D_{ki}$, which means eq. $(1)$ becomes:
$$
\tag{2}
D_{ii} \leq 2 D_{ik}
$$
If $D$ is Traceless, however, it is true that $D_{ii}=0$ so the inequality in eq $(2)$ becomes
$$
\tag{3}
0 \leq D_{ik}
$$
If you multiply eq $(3)$ by $-1$ it becomes $D_{ik} \geq 0$, which is just a statement that $D$ is Nonegative.

So here is my question:

> **If $D$ is Real, Traceless, Symmetric and Metric, dos that imply that it is Nonegative, or is there some kind of restriction on the triplet of indices in the triangle inequality? For instance, that they should be distinct.**

If that is the case then an EDM has to satisfy only the following properties:

1. **Real:** $D_{ii} \in \mathbb{R} \forall i,j$
2. **Traceless:** $D_{ii} = 0$
3. **Symmetric:** $D_{ij} = D_{ji}$
4. **Metric:** $D_{ij} \leq D_{ik} + D_{kj} \forall i,j,k$

Comment: Your argument looks right to me: $0 = D_{ii} \leq D_{ij} + D_{ji} = 2 D_{ij}$ where the first equality is the diagonal being zero, the second is metric, and the third is symmetry. By the way, I wouldn't call property 2 traceless (which I would interpret as $\sum_i D_{ii} = 0$), what you have is a stronger property that every element of the diagonal is zero.

Comment: Proof checked but https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info your post, though very long, was not precise enough. You should have pointed which step you were doubting.

Comment: @AnneBauval I have editted the question itself to be precise about my doubt. I don't know whether the triangle inequality is stated, in its original for, to any triplet of indices or whether it is supposed to be valid only for three distinct points. Either the matrix has to be nonegative or the triangle inequality isn't defined for non-distinct points. One or the other.

Comment: If you built the matrix out of distances of points in $\mathbb{R}^m$ (or any metric space), then $D_{ij} \leq D_{ik} + D_{kj}$ holds for any triple. So this is probably the natural property to require on an "abstract" EDM.

Comment: Wikipedia had $D_{ij}$ the square of the distance.

Comment: $D_{ii}=0,$ so $D_{ii}\leq D_{ik}+D_{ki}$ is trivial from $D_{ik},D_{k,i}\geq 0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews when its $d^2_{ij}$ then it's not the triangle inequality, the identity is something to do with the inner product matrices. $g_{ij}=(1/2) (d^2_{i1}+d^2_{1j} - d^2_{ij})$ I belive.

Comment: @urquiza So? My question is, is your definition of EDM correct? Wikipedia gives the triangle inequality is $$\sqrt{a_{ij}}\leq \sqrt{a_{ik}}+\sqrt{a_{kj}}.$$ Sure, if you don't square the distance, that inequality becomes less messy, but if you use a term, you shouldn't  define it to something different from common practice if you want to communicate with people. Or make it clear you are talking about a variant.

Comment: In particular, the squared distance definition gives algebraic properties to the matrix, which do not exist for the distance matrix.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have defiend what $D_{ij}$ means. Third paragraph from the top to bottom. The one which starts as "So let $D$ (...)" contains a line stating that (...) each entry $D_{ij}$ represents the Euclidean distance between two points $\vec p_i$ and $\vec p_j$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$". Thus, I am not using distances square, but the distances themselves.

Comment: Right, but you don't make clear up front this is an alternate definition, contrary to usual practice, so people trying to help you who look up the term will get the wrong definition. Communication is key. You need to let people know when you are using the term that it might not help to Google since you are not using the term normally. Help people help you.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have added an edit close to the line where I define the entries of matrix $D$ to let readers know what I mean by the entries and the relationship between my definition and the common use and why I chose to maintain the irregular definition.